Трансляция аудипотока через промежуточный вебсервис на фронт? python, js
Как сделать? На фронте вызывается через xhr вебсервис на fastapi. Там идёт вызов chatgpt tts:
from openai import OpenAI

    client = OpenAI()
    
    response = client.audio.speech.create(
        model="tts-1",
        voice="alloy",
        input="Hello world! This is a streaming test.",
    )
    
    response.stream_to_file("output.mp3)

как мне это вернуть на фронт и там проиграть?
openai пишет в доке:

The Speech API provides support for real time audio streaming using chunk transfer encoding. This means that the audio is able to be played before the full file has been generated and made accessible.

